# How to synchronize Google Play after a ROM change

Tags: applications, google-play-store, sync

After flashing a new ROM I recovered some of my installed application from a backup (it was also an opportunity to clean up). 
Unfortunately the view Google Play has is the one from the old ROM (all apps installed before the flash).

Is there a way to synchronize (one way) the view so that what is visible in "My Apps" on Google Play corresponds to what is actually currently installed in my phone?

Answer (score 1):

[Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) has an option to re-link apps to the Play Store.